# Tomcat 7 - JDBCRealm login

Tags: authentication, tomcat7, jdbcrealm

I'm using the JDBCRealm with tomcat 7. I want to build a simple login page.
This is my login form:

[Login Form](http://jsfiddle.net/kj8Wd/)

and my web.xml content is:

```
 <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/user/login.jsp</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/user/login-failed.html</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
 </login-config>
```

I want to redirect the user to some a.jsp page once he was authenticated.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Thing I understood that you want to redirect your user depends upon the role.Suppose if user is admin then he/she should be redirected to admin.jsp (for example) and if user is on manger role and he/she should be redirected to manager.jsp.

Let us suppose you have two roles admin and manager defined in your JDBCRealm

You can do this by Creating a servlet in project for example LoginServlet.java

So things you have to set are:

1. Create your login.jsp and login-failed.html as you mentioned.
2. Create to two jsp pages admin.jsp and manager.jsp  under any folder in WebContent of dynamic web project
   say  :

WebContent/htmlPages/admin.jsp    put 
    `<h4>Welcome Admin</h4>text in body tag.`

WebContent/htmlPages/manager.jsp  put 
    `<h4>Welcome Admin</h4>text in body tag.`

1. In LoginServlet.jsp in doGet MEthod
   put this simple  code:

   `if(request.isUserInRole("admin"))
                {
              response.sendRedirect("htmlPages/admin.jsp");

               }
   if(request.isUserInRole("manager")){
              response.sendRedirect("htmlPages/manager.jsp");

        }`
2. After that you have to set welcome-files as the  login servletin web.xml
   e.g.
   Suppose IN web.xml your servlet entry is

   <servlet>
       <description></description>
       <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
       <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>Fully classified name of LoginServlet</servlet-class>
     </servlet>
     <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>

Then get url pattern from Servlet Mapping and put it in welcome file list without any slash:
like

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>loginServlet</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

Be sure that no slash has been included. Welcome file attribute should be without slash as i put in code  loginServlet.

Run this code.:-) You would get redirected to appropriate jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. That isn't how FORM authentication works. The user requests a page. If it requires authentication then they receive the login page rather than the page they requested. They then enter their credentials and if valid get presented with the page they originally requests.

If you insist on misusing the FORM authentication process you can set the landingPage attribute of the org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator. See the docs (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Form_Authenticator_Valve) for full details.